# WordPress video shortcode adds "?_=2" to the end of my src option

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Has anybody had this experience? My WordPress (WordPress 5.4.2 running Twenty Seventeen Child theme) has an XYZ Code Snippet that echoes

```
do_shortcode('[video src="https://mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs/C0112.mp4" preload=none]');
```

but somewhere in the process, a four character string is added to the end of the src so that I get

> Media error: Format(s) not supported or source(s) not foundDownload
> File: https://mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs/C0112.mp4?_=2

when the page renders.

Comment: Is in the page source? If so, it's a PHP thing. If not, it's a JavaScript thing. If it's PHP, look at the `add_shortcode` function that's creating the `[video]` shortcode. If it's a JavaScript thing, you'll need to dig through all the scripts.

Comment: The query string at the end of the URL will not affect the detected file location or media type.  Did you verify that https://mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs/C0112.mp4 is a valid working URL?  If it is, you should be able to append `?sdfsdfsd;k_sdfsd` any kind of query string at the end without making any difference.

Comment: You might want to list any plugins that you're using, what your Webb server is, etc, in order to help diagnose.

Comment: Why do you have mp4 video files lingering in a folder named `securepdfs` to begin with? Sure that’s not what causes the problem to begin with? (A plugin trying to prevent PDFs uploaded to such a specific folder might append these URL parameters automatically at some point, to be able to provide its “protecting” functionality, or something like that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the appended string; the problem was that the two mp4 files that had been uploaded were both over 1 Gb in size. Once I had converted them down to a more realistic bit rate and got the sizes down to below 50M, the mp4's rendered successfully.